# sharing data between master and slave threads in kdb

Tags: kdb

What is the ideal method to sharing read only data between the master and slave threads? From my understanding there are two options:

1. Set shared data as global variable in main so that the slave threads can read them.
2. Pass shared variables to slave threads as parameters.

From my experiments, there is hardly any difference in performance even with big data set. In fact, 1) has slightly worse performance over 2). I know that for 2), kdb will serialize and serialize parameters. Does it do the same for 1)? That would explain the degradation of performance considering the global variable is bigger in size than thread specific parameter. Are there alternative methods to do this?

Secondly, as slave threads cannot modify global variables. I reckon the only way to share results with main thread is returning them back. Please comment if this is not the case.

**EDIT: Performance is measured in terms of runtime before and after call to peach.**

Answer (score 0):

Passing values into a function via peach like this

`{}[v;] peach vector`

sounds nice, and works well, unless v is very large. Each thread gets a copy (even if v is a global).

So the answer depends on your use case. Do you have enough RAM? Can you afford the memory copy given the number of threads? If the answer is yes, then you can afford to do this without too much ill affect (remember allocation will affect time).

I prefer to use globals for this reason.

Comment: Ok. is there a performance impact of using globals? In my case, when I use globals, I instead see a degradation in performance.  MY program is not memory bound. Is it possible global variables are copied over to each thread heap? Or is there significant cost of accessing globals defined in main thread heap from individual threads? Does it involve serialization?

Comment: no globals aren't mem copied AFAIK, accessing globals should be very fast. How are you measuring degradation of performance? Can you update your question with an example to replicate?

Comment: I am measuring through simple run time of program, taking difference between start and end time before and after call to peach. I will try to create an example.